# WakeLock.release() switches off screen even if the user was interacting with the app

Tags: android, wakelock

My app wakes the phone from standby and turns on the screen (`SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK`). I can't use the WindowManager-flags approach, as my app may already be running in the background.

The problem is that once the user dismisses my app and the WakeLock is released, the screen turns off immediately, even if the user was interacting with the app (or the homescreen, which briefly shows while the app is being closed).

Would using the `ON_AFTER_RELEASE`-flag help?

Comment: Screen was off, app wakes up the phone, user is done with your app, screen goes off to initial state. Isn't this a consistent behavior? Why is that bad?

Comment: I think this is intended behavior. The documentation even mentions the following: "The screen may turn off shortly after you release the wake lock, or it may not if there are other wake locks still held."

Comment: I have the same situation as Nick. The behavior is NOT what the user expects. Users NEVER expect their screen to go totally black when exiting an app or activity. If they have a screen timeout, that should be honored by the OS. Android does NOT honor this when a wakelock is released. This is a flaw in their design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to use the [`ON_AFTER_RELEASE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ON_AFTER_RELEASE) flag.

> When this wake lock is released, poke the user activity timer so the screen stays on for a little longer.

Comment: Thanks, this did indeed fix it!

Comment: This will not work if you lock the screen immediately when terminating the activity.

Comment: Hmm, I tested Geobits' answer and it works fine on my device, but some of my users are still reporting that their screen turns off when I release the wakelock...is it known to not work consistently across devices?

Comment: This will not work if you set your screen timeout less than 30 seconds or less. I have a navigation app, I set the wake lock before navigating and release it after navigation is ended. For this case it will not override the screen time out.